# Sending email through REST API gives 401 unauthorized access error

Tags: rest-api, email

I am posting the request to send the email but get 401 unauthorized access. This is with a fresh token so token is not timed out I know. Below is the request that I am using. I do not have any issues getting any format error with the way I am trying to send, but I should not be getting 401.

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/{sendId}/send

```
{  Content - Type = [application / json], Authorization = [Bearer jhlkigh87t7t8ggbhg(this is my fake access token)]
}, 
{  "From": {
        "Address": "xxx@xxx.com",
        "Name": "xxx@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "xxx@xxx.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "rohitmangal@biglots.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "East",
                "City": "columbus",
                "State": "OH"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I am using application id in place of sendId, is this correct?

Reference: https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your headers.

You have defined your headers as part of the message body, but they should be part of the post request object. Also, the headers appear to be formatted incorrectly.

You have this:

```
{Content - Type = [application / json], Authorization = [Bearer jhlkigh87t7t8ggbhg(this is my fake access token)]}
```

But your headers should look like this:

```
Content-Type = application/json
Authorization = Bearer jhlkigh87t7t8ggbhg(this is my fake access token)
```